# How to run a Flask application on the web?

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask app that I created and successfully run on localhost. Now, I want to make it available for others to use on a website. How can I accomplish this using GitHub? Is it possible to deploy an interactive app that receives data from clients?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are various platforms that you can deploy on, though asking for recommendations here is off-topic - see, for example https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: See Flask docs on deploying to production; https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/deploying/index.html

Answer (score 2):

To make it available to other users, you need to:

- Choose a WSGI server;
- Install necessary dependencies & configure the server;
- Configure your Flask app;
- Launch the WSGI server;

GitHub is a platform to share, collaborate on source code, etc. GitHub is not made to host complex websites since you can only use GitHub Pages and GitHub pages only deals with static files.

It's not currently possible to deploy interactive apps on GitHub.